# How to find dcitionary value in some file and replace it with some value using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two files `config.py`where script is written to read and write dictionary  & `dict.py` contains dictionary. I want to find `key('server')` in `dict.py` and replace one of its key with some value.Please note that existing other keys should exist ,only `server['hostname']` field should be replaced.Can someone tell me how this can be done,i have tried following way

## dict.py

```
server = {'hostname': 'ocm-server-31.com',
               'user': 'root',
               'password': 'radia123'
              }

in_servers = {
        'robotwin': {'user': 'root',
                        'esxiuname':'root',
                        'esxipwd':'gone2far',
                        'vmname':'robot12_221'
                        }

      }

csa_server = {'hostname': 'opsware.com',
              'user': 'admin',
              'password': 'cloud'
             }
```

## Config.py

```
server = {'hostname': 'hyi01lr0bsaehost.com',
               'user': 'root',
               'password': 'opsware',
              }
with open('dict.py','r') as f_in, open('dict.py','w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in :
        if line['server'] == 'server':
            replace_text = f_out.replace(server['hostname'])
            print "Text found "

        else:
            print "Text not found "
```

Comment: This is a story, not a question.

Comment: @timgeb if you dont like my way of questioning , please ignore and comment if you know the answer only . I am a learner and new to programming.

Comment: Maybe you could try to rephrase your question for additional clarity? I too find it unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks @SebastianHietsch for your feedback. I have updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Replace variables in file
with open('conf.py', 'r+') as f:
    content = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    for line in content:
       f.write(content.replace('search_text', 'new_text'))
```